# process angular function on view renedring

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have image url in this format in database

```
http://www.nobrok.com/roomrent1/public/uploads/5269/b4a3263f52c1c4725096ee299fa2c64051cb9b4d.jpg::
```

i am trying to pass image url to a angular controllers method like this

```
<img src="sizeImg(comment.pictures)">
```

and i have written a function to process the url like this

```
$scope.sizeImg = function(pictures){

            return 'http://www.nobrok.com/roomrent1/public/uploads/5269/b4a3263f52c1c4725096ee299fa2c64051cb9b4d.jpg';
    }
```

but the function is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass javascript directly into into src, and the angular documentation for ngSrc mentions "Using Angular markup like {{hash}} in a src attribute doesn't work right now" Try ng-src.

```
<img ng-src="{{ sizeImg(comment.pictures) }}">
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc

Codepen example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gfvIr